# Entity Framework Logging not working on exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, logging

I have implemented Entity Framework Logging according to the guideline from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx). However, it only logs when there is no exception!!! I created an `system.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` by assigning more than allowed characters. My code is:

```
Databasecontext context=new DatabaseContext();
TableCity tbCity;
var logger = new MyLogger();           
context.Database.Log = l => logger.Log("Table-tableNews", l);
tbCity.City ="sdkjfaksdjfsdjfjasdfjsdjfjdfjdjfjasdfjlasdjfljdfjdadsfdf";//varchar(25) in dbase
.......... //code removed for clarity
context.TableName.Add(tbCity);
try{
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {}
```

My Log method

```
 public void Log(string component, string messages)
 {
    //contents here, which works as desired
 }
```

Do I need to implement differently to log exceptions?

Comment: Yes, logging the SQL generated is different than logging exceptions. If an exception occurs, no SQL is generated. For exceptions, use a tool like [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks Steve. I already use ELMAH in another project. I was looking to try something different, though, I like ELMAH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would have [scrolled down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx#Interception%20building%20blocks) on the link you mentioned you would have come across the `IDbCommandInterceptor` interface. It is much more feature rich and it can tell whether the query was executed with succes or with a failure.

An example implementation could be:

```
public class LogDbCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        interceptionContext.SetUserState("start", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"sql command: {command.CommandText}, hasFailed: {HasFailed(interceptionContext)}, duration: {CalculateDuration(interceptionContext)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"parameters: {FormatParams(command.Parameters)}, exception: {interceptionContext.Exception?.Message}");
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        interceptionContext.SetUserState("start", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"sql command: {command.CommandText}, hasFailed: {HasFailed(interceptionContext)}, duration: {CalculateDuration(interceptionContext)}");
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        interceptionContext.SetUserState("start", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"sql command: {command.CommandText}, hasFailed: {HasFailed(interceptionContext)}, duration: {CalculateDuration(interceptionContext)}");
    }

    private static double CalculateDuration<T>(DbCommandInterceptionContext<T> context)
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - (DateTime)context.FindUserState("start")).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private static bool HasFailed<T>(DbCommandInterceptionContext<T> context)
    {
        return context.OriginalException != null || (context.IsAsync && context.TaskStatus != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
    }

    private static string FormatParams(ICollection dbParameterCollection)
    {
        if (dbParameterCollection.Count == 0)
            return string.Empty;

        var parameterDescriptor = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (SqlParameter parameter in dbParameterCollection)
        {
            parameterDescriptor.AppendFormat("{0} {1}: {2}, ", parameter.DbType, parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value);
        }

        return parameterDescriptor.ToString().TrimEnd(' ', ',');
    }
}
```

where `Console.WriteLine` can be replaced of course with your own logger.

As you can see you can read an exception using the [OriginalException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt137188(v=vs.113).aspx) property. The other properties of interest are listened [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn343478(v=vs.113).aspx)

A short guide to registering your implementation can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_command_interception.htm) as well:

> Registering Interceptors
>   Once a class that implements one or more of the interception interfaces has been created it can be registered with EF using the DbInterception class
>
> Interceptors can also be registered at the app-domain level using the DbConfiguration code-based configuration
>
> You can also configure interceptor using the app.config file

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will be back after implementation.

Comment: @curious.netter Hi there, did it work for you or did you run into other problems?

Comment: I had been very busy with other project, will check it asap and will come back.

Comment: It works but there is no method SetUserState but there's a property called UserState. The concept is same, I just tweaked little bit so that it works. Thanks.